# Should I Worry About SQL Injection When Using wp_insert_post?

Tags: security

I have created a form to insert posts via front-end to users.

I use `wp_insert_post` function.

Should I worry about SQL injection or Does `wp_insert_post` function handle it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress DOES take care of SQL injection and  for you. See the **Security** section on this [page](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/). The `wp_insert_post()` function runs through [`sanitize_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_post/).

Be aware that malicious or unintended code can still be inserted:

> "You may wish, however, to remove HTML, JavaScript, and PHP tags from
>   the `post_title` and any other fields. Surprisingly, WordPress does
>   not do this automatically. This can be easily done by using the
>   [wp_strip_all_tags()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_strip_all_tags/) function and is **especially useful when building
>   front-end post submission forms**."

Should you not want to strip ALL tags, [Validating Sanitizing and Escaping User Data](https://codex.wordpress.org/Validating_Sanitizing_and_Escaping_User_Data) is a good page to start looking for specific sanitation rules that are built in. You can never be too secure.

Comment: I am assuming "SQL injection" is ANY insecure data from untrustworthy users.

Comment: I think the answer is confusing, you start with a wrong answer and then correct yourself. Maybe a total rewrite which will describe in a little more orgenized way what core will do and what it will not is in order ;)